# SOAP message transformation using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am working on an application where I need to send a SOAP request to call a method "authenticateCustomer" with some parameters like "customerID", "password" etc. On the basis of a parameter say "customer ID",  application has to send a SOAP response. I need to apply XSLT to prepare SOAP response to be sent back by application. But I am unable to generate proper response from server. Following is the code:

**SOAP Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eps="http://www.eps.in.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
          <eps:authenticateCustomer>
             <eps:customerDetail>
                <eps:customerID>2</eps:customerID>
                <eps:password>abc</eps:password>
             </eps:customerDetail>
          </eps:authenticateCustomer>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response expected:
When say customerID is equal to 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eps="http://www.eps.in.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <eps:authenticateCustomer>
         <eps:customerDetail>
            <eps:customerID>VALUE OF CUSTOMER ID</eps:customerID>
            <eps:password>VALUE OF PASSWORD</eps:password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:saltId>sss</eps:saltId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:systemID>SYSTEM1</eps:systemID>
            <eps:sourceSystem>FDWEB</eps:sourceSystem>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:status>ACTIVE</eps:status>
         </eps:customerDetail>
      </eps:authenticateCustomer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And when customerID is other than 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eps="http://www.eps.in.com"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body <eps:authenticateCustomer>
         <eps:customerDetail>
            <eps:customerID>VALUE OF CUSTOMER ID</eps:customerID>
            <eps:password>VALUE OF PASSWORD</eps:password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:saltId>sss</eps:saltId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:systemID>SYSTEM1</eps:systemID>
            <eps:sourceSystem>FDWEB</eps:sourceSystem>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:status>ACTIVE</eps:status>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:saltId>dhdkhf</eps:saltId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:systemID>dfhdgf</eps:systemID>
            <eps:sourceSystem>FDWEB</eps:sourceSystem>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:status>ACTIVE</eps:status>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:facebookUID>FB001</eps:facebookUID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:facebookURL>helloo</eps:facebookURL>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:googleUID>GG190</eps:googleUID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <eps:googleURL>google</eps:googleURL>
            <eps:domainName>HND</eps:domainName>
         </eps:customerDetail>
      </eps:authenticateCustomer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

======================================================================

I am trying to apply following XSLT to prepare dynamic response, but response is not getting prepared:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:eps="http://www.eps.out.com" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="customerID" select="//customerID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="password" select="//password"/>

        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eps="http://www.eps.out.com">
            <soapenv:Header />
            <soapenv:Body>
                <eps:customerID><xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:customerID>
                <xsl:message>Hello World!</xsl:message>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$customerID = 2">
                    <eps:authenticateCustomerResponse>
                            <eps:customerData>
                                <eps:authCode>AC<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:authCode>
                                <eps:customerID><xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:customerID>
                                <eps:saltId>SA<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:saltId>
                                <eps:sourceSystem>SS<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:sourceSystem>
                                <eps:mdmID>?</eps:mdmID>
                                <eps:existingSystem>?</eps:existingSystem>
                                <eps:creationDate>?</eps:creationDate>
                                <eps:lastUpdateDate>?</eps:lastUpdateDate>
                                <eps:createdBy>?</eps:createdBy>
                                <eps:updatedBy>?</eps:updatedBy>
                                <eps:status>?</eps:status>
                            </eps:customerData>
                            <eps:error>
                                <eps:errorCode>?</eps:errorCode>
                                <eps:errorDetails>?</eps:errorDetails>
                            </eps:error>
                        </eps:authenticateCustomerResponse>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <eps:authenticateCustomerResponse>
                            <eps:customerData>
                                <eps:authCode>AC<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:authCode>
                                <eps:customerID><xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:customerID>
                                <eps:saltId>SA<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:saltId>
                                <eps:sourceSystem>SS<xsl:value-of select="$customerID" /></eps:sourceSystem>
                                <eps:mdmID>?</eps:mdmID>
                                <eps:existingSystem>?</eps:existingSystem>
                                <eps:creationDate>?</eps:creationDate>
                                <eps:lastUpdateDate>?</eps:lastUpdateDate>
                                <eps:createdBy>?</eps:createdBy>
                                <eps:updatedBy>?</eps:updatedBy>
                                <eps:status>?</eps:status>
                                <eps:systemID>?</eps:systemID>
                                <eps:password>?</eps:password>
                                <eps:facebookUID>?</eps:facebookUID>
                                <eps:facebookURL>?</eps:facebookURL>
                                <eps:facebookUpdateFlag>?</eps:facebookUpdateFlag>
                                <eps:facebookUpdateDate>?</eps:facebookUpdateDate>
                                <eps:googleUID>?</eps:googleUID>
                                <eps:googleURL>?</eps:googleURL>
                                <eps:googleUpdateFlag>?</eps:googleUpdateFlag>
                                <eps:googleUpdateDate>?</eps:googleUpdateDate>
                                <eps:domainName>?</eps:domainName>
                            </eps:customerData>
                            <eps:error>
                                <eps:errorCode>?</eps:errorCode>
                                <eps:errorDetails>?</eps:errorDetails>
                            </eps:error>
                        </eps:authenticateCustomerResponse>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you use to generate the request, you could use a native SoapClient that would wrap all the things correctly.
For example, in PHP, you could use [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) to create a PHP package that will ease you the way you send the request without having to alter any XML request

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am working on IBM DataPower. Here, DataPower Device receives SOAP request and it requires an XSL to be used while sending back reply. I just need to tell Datapower to use a particular XSL for sending reply to this particular type of SOAP request. So basically it is language independent. I just need a correct XSL. It seems the problem is in namespace usage in the xslt that i have posted in original question

Answer (score 0):

Here's the few mistakes you have made

1. The namespace in your example is "http://www.eps.in.com", and in XSLT you have defined as "http://www.eps.out.com"
2. You cannot ignore the namespace while querying, use below to store value in variable: `<xsl:variable name="customerID" select="//eps:customerID" />`
3. The XSLT looks like for SOAP response, where as your samples looks like SOAP request